# php server side variable loosing value when passed to a method

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am writing a php site using zend framework 1.1, in one of the pages i have a variable that is set in server side from a query to a database.
in the same site i have a functionality that sends an email to the admin if an error happens with the trace of the error while the user sees a friendly error message.

in few of the pages, while the pages are loaded correctly with the correct information from the database i receive many emails showing a variable that looses its value and turns to NULL.

the variable can't be NULL otherwise the information that is displayed could not have been displayed, also, when dumping the value of the variable to the screen i can see they are correct and not NULL.

the variable turns to NULL when i pass it to a method of another class to actually retrieve the information from the database.

below is the code:

```
$Info = $PrjInfo->getInfo(Id);              
    $Id = $Info['ID'];
    Zend_Debug::dump($Id);                        
    $project = $PrjInfo->getProjectSpecificationInfo($Id);
    Zend_Debug::dump($project);
```

both dump commands will show valid values for the variables that receive however the system will always send an email showing "$project = $PrjInfo->getProjectSpecificationInfo(NULL);"
as if this method was called with a NULL value.

appreciate any help.

Comment: `$Info = $PrjInfo->getInfo(Id);` Is `Id` defined as a constant? or should this be `$Id`? or did you mean `ID` (case-sensitive)?

Comment: sorry, it should be $Info = $PrjInfo->getInfo($Id);